# Capistrano executing a shell script error su: must be run from a terminal

Tags: capistrano3, pty

su - $USER -c "$CMD stop > /dev/null 2>&1" yields this error

su: must be run from a terminal. When set :pty, true in deploy.rb the prompt holds on. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Which prompt? Is it prompting for a password? Are you running the server deploy as root?

Comment: no I am not running as root

Answer (score 1):

The `su` command generally doesn't work well with Capistrano. The preferred way to run a command as a different user involves passwordless sudo: http://capistranorb.com/documentation/getting-started/authentication-and-authorisation/#authorisation